# command line ps has stopped working correctly after an update

Tags: command-line, memory

I use to be able to run this ps command from the terminal:

ps -u `whoami` -o pid,rss,command

But recently the RSS size returned are all 0!

```
ps -u `whoami` -o pid,rss,command
158      0 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock
159      0 /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/MacOS/SystemUIServer
160      0 /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
165      0 /usr/sbin/pboard
```

unless I run it with sudo

```
sudo ps -u `whoami` -o pid,rss,command
158  17556 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock
159  22488 /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/MacOS/SystemUIServer
160  82176 /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
165    840 /usr/sbin/pboard
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or how to get the original functionality back?

Comment: What level of OS are you running? The ps -u does not work for me on 10.6.7 - ps -U works so either your OS is different or your path has an alternate ps binary or I'm missing something else obvious.  (FYI MD5 (/bin/ps) = 32a504d1010b2e40beebe8c30ff7bf6d )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 10.6.7 and your

```
ps -u `whoami` -o pid,rss,command
```

producing

```
  PID    RSS COMMAND
  180    696 /sbin/launchd
  185  19108 /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/MacOS/SystemUIServer
  189     32 /usr/sbin/pboard
  .... etc ....
```

so, the problem is in your system. So, what return this:

```
ls -l /bin/ps
```

should this

```
-r-sr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  134816 12 okt  2010 /bin/ps
```

if your ps has other permissions, repair with:

```
sudo chown root /bin/ps
sudo chgrp wheel /bin/ps
sudo chmod 4555 /bin/ps
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks on the face of it to be a permissions issue.

I would try and Repair Permissions as per http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452

Comment: I suppose if the set-user-ID-on-execution bit on /bin/ps (or whatever ps is in the path first) were gone this makes great sense... `$ ls -la /bin/ps
-r-sr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  134816 May 18  2009 /bin/ps`

Comment: The repair permissions might have worked, how ever I ran `sudo chmod 4555 /bin/ps` and the issue has been fixed.  

The permissions were   
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel   132K 18 May  2009 /bin/ps*

Now  
-r-sr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel   132K 18 May  2009 /bin/ps*